# Is there a security risk by letting users choose an associated model via a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, activerecord

I have a User who has Clients, and Clients have Expenses. I have a form that creates a new expense and on that form the user needs to select which client the expense is for. Here's how I did it:

```
= form_for(@expense) do |f|
...
   = f.select :client_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@possible_clients, "id", "name"), {:include_blank => true}, :class => "span10"
```

and the controller:

```
def create
    @expense = Expense.new(params[:expense])
    @expense.user = current_user
    @expense.date = convert_to_db_date(params[:expense][:date])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @expense.save
        format.html { redirect_to expenses_path }
        format.json { render json: @expense, status: :created, location: @expense }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the expense model:

```
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :invoice

  ## ACCESSIBLE ##
  attr_accessible :amount, :category, :date, :invoice_id, :note, :reimbursed, :user_id, :client_id
```

and the client model:

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :expenses
```

So I'm just thinking there's a big security issue here. Since a user can submit any id for the client associated with the expense...they can assign any client, right? Is there a better way of doing this? Is there some rails magic that prevents security issues?

Comment: When you mean a user can submit any id for the client associated with the expense do you mean by the user typing in the url for a particular client id and altering the expense. Because in this case I believe you would have some sort of filter that would check if the user is associated with that client. If that user is associated with the client then therefore they can alter the expense - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters - See Section 7

Comment: In this case you are enforcing the user to be the logged user (assuming you are using devise). The only problem I can see you will have is that a user can send any value for amount and reimbursement.

Comment: What I mean is a user can submit the form with any client_id...so they can associate their expense instance with any client instance they choose

Comment: @fotanus the user can also submit any value for client_id

Comment: @MatthewBerman yes, but in the next step you are overwriting it: `@expense.user = current_user`. If you pass a `user_id`, do you have a problem or not? Seems to be the easiest way to tell. Use a firefox extension to issue a post if you don't know how to do it manually, or a hidden field.

Comment: I'm not worried about someone trying to mess with user_id...but rather to submit a client_id that isn't actually one of their clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is a security issue. In cases where you need to restrict access to associated records, you should always select from that restricted set on the server side - don't trust the client side to respect your wishes. I would remove `client_id` from `attr_accessible` and only allow it to be assigned manually.

The best way to handle this would be to create a new class that handles the management of expenses, but if you're looking for a quick fix, you can use the controller action (but please note: I would not leave this in the controller in the long term).

Extract the client id from the params, use it to grab the record from the current user's clients, and assign that manually to the expense:

```
client_id = params[:expense].delete(:client_id)
@expense = current_user.expenses.new(params[:expense])
@expense.client = current_user.clients.find(client_id)
```

Comment: when you say create a new class that handles the management of expenses...can you point me to an example? isn't that overkill? I understand your "quick fix" method but since you said don't use that long-term...i'd like to understand your other method.

Comment: Matthew, that's potentially a never-ending discussion, but here are a few links to give you the general idea (I have not read these, so I can't vouch for them personally): [Rails is not your application](http://blog.firsthand.ca/2011/10/rails-is-not-your-application.html), [Does my Rails App Need a Service Layer?](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/01/10/does-my-rails-app-need-a-service-layer/), [Hexagonal Rails (conference talk)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGN4RFkhH2M)

Comment: And to answer another question - it's almost never overkill to create more classes. I find it's always better to create another class when you find that one of your existing classes (say, a Rails controller) is doing things it shouldn't be responsible for.

Comment: got it. so I'm going to take the quick fix method for now and research the long term method. however, i'm having to reproduce a lot of code (each create/update methods in each controller)...kind of annoying but otherwise I just need to do it the right way